# How do i use the i-reports in the project?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, struts

I want to take the report using the i-report. I'm the new one . So i really don't know how to use the i-report in the project . Can anyone give me the suggestion to use the i-reports or is there any alternate reporting software instead of i-report.

Answer (score 1):

Design and create *.jasper* files from iReport tool and keep them in a specific location of your server machine. At the run time use those files, pass a datasourse object and export the report with JasperExport. Your report would be exported.

To do so, first create a JasperPrint object and then a JRExporter object. Here is a sample code for PDF export.

> JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename, jasperParam, conn);

```
JRExporter response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);
            exporter.exportReport();
```